# Shorten array in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript

How can I make this code shorter, is there any way? I feel there's too much repeating..

```
    var bokstaver1:Array = new Array("a", "b", "c");
    var bokstaver2:Array = ["d","e","f"];
    var bokstaver:Array = New Array();

bokstaver[0] = "b";
bokstaver[1] = "i";
bokstaver[2] = "l";
bokstaver[3] = "l";
bokstaver[4] = "e";
```

I'm all new here so if this is not a way to ask a question on here please don't hasten insults.

Comment: Your question's fine. Can you however explain what the relationship between bokstaver1 and bokstaver2 is, and why you didn't simply type bokstaver = ["b", "i", "l", "l", "e"] ?

Comment: My teacher taught us this way, but looking at it I knew there had to be a way easier formatting for it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How can I remove commas when tracing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this easy way:

```
 var bokstaver:Array = "bille".split("");
 trace(bokstaver); // outputs: b,i,l,l,e
```

Comment: How can I remove the commas? And output it just as "bille"

Comment: bokstaver.join(''); but why not use a string instead ?

Comment: @user3030785 as Arlaud Agbe Pierre just said: `bokstaver.join('');`